# merging two source columns in informatica

Tags: informatica

I want to combine two sources in Informatica such that source 1 has column with some missing values, source 2 has that column with those exact values. Then how to combine into a single column in a target

Comment: Just use a joiner!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should use a UNION!